# Java - Restore JFrame/Drawing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

Using Java, I generate a new `JFrame` frame and load an image into it along with some buttons:

[image]

I then click on 'Classify' in order to detect the main area of interest and this produces an image such as the following:

[image]

However, when I click 'Classify' once again, the first drawings (green and red circles) remain on the image and they are then classified.  How can I do it so that when I click 'Classify' for a second/third/n-th time, the image is reset (all drawings/circles removed) back how it was before 'Classify' was clicked?

I have a 'Reset Image' `JButton`, but I have yet to implement this (hence my question!).

Many thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This is a general query, so an SSCCE is unnecessary for this type of question; furthermore, help was provided very quickly (approximately within five minutes of posting). Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory usage efficiency aside, you could store the initial graphics state into a `BufferedImage`. And upon clicking <kbd>Classify</kbd>, ***draw onto a copy*** of the `Graphics` object of that image instead, and then paint the area with it.

And upon clicking <kbd>Reset Image</kbd>, just draw the image directly to the area.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  May I please ask for some sample code as I cannot figure this out?

Comment: @Mick, Most everything should be documented in the [`BufferedImage` api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)